# Passing parameters to a function in Lua 4

Tags: function, lua, arguments, lua-4.0

I have a function that will take any number of arguments and then do stuff with those arguments.

For instance, `min(3,9,1,2)` or `min(2,1)` or `min(5,1,7)`.

However, in Lua 4 how do I feed the arguments to the function from within another routine when I don't know beforehand how *many* arguments there will be? Maybe I have an array containing a bunch of strings, but it's a different number of strings each time, and I need to pass those strings to the function as arguments before getting any results.

Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I posted the same question seven years ago.

Comment: This question doesn't mention absence of `call` function, which was _one_ the of preferred ways to do that at the time. These questions are similar, but this one has wider scope and brings something more to the topic. Even if original intentions were the same, I suggest to resolve this question in its scope and leave it be for future reference (and simply for better search results in future).

Answer (score 3):

I would populate a table and then use [`call`](https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#call):

```lua
a = {n = 2; arg1, arg2}
tinsert(a, arg3)
call(func, a)
```

In short `call` applies array part of table as arguments to a function:

```lua
call(func, a) --> func(a[1], a[2], ..., a[n])
```

Good luck with 4.0! Haven't seen that one around in a while.